# Entire YouTube Comments section under videos disappeared for account after viewing comment history

Tags: youtube

Comments refuse to load under any video now when logged into an account I viewed my Google activity for. It is not an extension issue as it still persists when I disable all of them, and my other YouTube accounts can view comments normally. It's only happening for one account.

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to me. Cleared the cache, reset browser, only happened to one account.
I presume that account, somehow, got blacklisted by YouTube - someone probably was offended by something I wrote and reported me. (I don't troll or act nasty, but the last thing I posted was on a science related channel disagreeing with someone - who was really nasty).